# Problema com extensão de tabela no Postgresql, Pessoa e Pessoa Física

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que tem um cadastro de pessoas, é um CRUD de Pessoa que pode ser tanto física quanto jurídica. o problema é que na minha concepção deveria ser criado no banco de dados uma `Pessoa` e uma `Pessoa Fisica` porém está criando apenas uma pessoa.

Tenho uma entidade `Pessoa`.

```
package entys;
```

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa", schema = "dremcom_drem")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)  
@Column(name="id")    
private Long id;
private String endereco;
private String cep;


public Long getId() {  
    return this.id;  
}
private String nome;


public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Pessoa() {
    super();
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getCep() {
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep) {
    this.cep = cep;
}
```

}

logo depois eu tenho um entidade de `Pessoa Fisica`

```
package entys;
```

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoaFisica", schema = "dremcom_drem")
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String cpf;
private String matricula;
private String rg;

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
public String getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}
public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}
public String getRg() {
    return rg;
}
public void setRg(String rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}
```

}
então estou fazendo um teste para inserir uma pessoa física.

```
package testeUnitario;
```

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import util.JPAUtil;
import entys.PessoaFisica;

public class TestePessoaFisica {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();

    pessoaFisica.setNome("Andrades");
    pessoaFisica.setEndereco("67 sul");
    pessoaFisica.setCep("7700000");
    pessoaFisica.setCpf("89076");
    pessoaFisica.setMatricula("fc2012");
    pessoaFisica.setRg("89765");

    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(pessoaFisica);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

}

o que acontece é que quando eu insiro no meu banco ele cria apenas uma pessoa e não cria uma pessoa física e apenas coloca aqueles campos em pessoa
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via de regra (claro que podem haver exceções), recomendaria a você dar preferência a usar composição ao invés de herança e usar a estratégia de herança de uma classe para cada tabela (Table per class).

Fazendo assim, acredito que o código da aplicação fica mais fácil de compreender, evoluir e manter.

Em todo caso, no seu exemplo específico, o "erro" de inserir apenas uma pessoa e não uma pessoa física deve ser porque você não configurou a annotation na sua classe mãe (Pessoa)

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

Referências úteis:

- http://www.dextra.com.br/hibernate-e-heranca-os-contras/
- http://blog.caelum.com.br/jpa-com-hibernate-heranca-e-mapeamentos/
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html

Comment: Marcelo, entendi o conceito e por que utilizar composição ao invés da herança, porem especificamente nesse projeto preciso utilizar herança pois vou ter de apresentado para um DBA que gosta de herança... mas já vi que ele está errado a respeito de consultas mais aprofundadas. uma pergunta onde coloco o Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) na Pessoa? outra pergunta eu não poderia deixar a pessoa como uma classe abstrata? assim geraria apenas pessaFisica e pessoajuridica no banco?

Comment: a annotation Inheritance você poderia coloca acima / antes do  annotation Entity

Comment: sim, você poderia deixar a pessoa como uma classe abstrata, mas você precisa testar e descobrir por conta própria os efeitos disso na sua aplicação tanto em termos de persistencia quanto em termos de regra de negócio. Por exemplo, e se seu sistema permitir você cadastrar uma pessoa e somente depois configurar ou detalhar se ela é fisica ou juridica? Isso você e o DBA precisam definir, tendo em vista os requisitos de negócio da aplicação que está sendo desenvolvida.

Comment: entendo obrigado pelas dicas mais uma vez.